# Windows batch copy files from subfolders to one folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, xcopy

I had tried to make batch script that copies all *.tif files located in D:\images(random named subfolders here) to d:\all.

```
xcopy D:\Downloads\*.TIF D:\temp\ /s
```

works, but it copies with all folder tree. I tried to use other keys, but its dont works.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`FOR` is your friend. Read `HELP FOR` on the `/R` option and the `%~nx` variable substitution; and then try this very simple code.

```
   pushd d:\downloads
   for /r %%a in (*.tif) do (
     echo COPY "%%a" "d:\temp\%%~nxa"
   )
   popd
```

watch carefully the results and then remove the `ECHO` command.

You will have to refine the code to cope with errors, duplicate names, edge cases, names with reserved characters, race conditions, cosmic events...

Comment: Separate files patterns with commas! Make a .bat and replace `d:\downloads` with `%1` and `d:\temp\%%~nxa` with `%2`. Then you will have a reusable command, I put my Dropbox\bin into PATH so I can use it in all my computers. A great bat script, thanks!

Comment: To automatically overwrite instead of asking for each one ad /y to the copy command.

Comment: Hehe, especially deal with `cosmic events` ;)

Answer (score 6):

Searched files using windows file explorer for e.g. *.gif , I got files in search window, used Edit=>Select All , copy and then pasted to desired folder. This copied all the gif files in all sub directories to single folder.
For large number of files, it sometimes hangs/not responding, but otherwise works ok.

Comment: This is actually a pretty easy way of doing it! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
pushd D:\Source
   for /r %%a in (*.?*) do (
       MOVE "%%a" "D:\Destination folder\%%~nxa"
   )
popd
```

Comment: this will l take all files from subfolder and move them to destination folder you can also change the move to copy

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the XXCOPY freeware. Works like XCOPY, but when you use a /SG parameter, it flattens the sub-directories. See how to use it [here](http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy16.htm).